# Como atualizar campo em tabela do SQL sem bloqueá-la?

Tags: sql

Tenho uma tabela com muitos registros em produção (quase 3 milhões), e preciso atualizar um campo com uma consulta bem simples:

```
UPDATE tabela SET enviado = 1 WHERE enviado is null
```

Serão atualizados cerca de 2,5 milhões.

O problema é que irá demorar muito, e enquanto isso a tabela vai ficar bloqueada, não sendo possível retornar os registros.

Tem como contornar isso?

Alguma consulta parecida com a `SELECT WITH(NOLOCK)`?

Observação: Não posso alterar a aplicação para fazer o `SELECT WITH(NOLOCK)`.

Comment: Nota: NOLOCK é um hint, você está meramente *sugerindo* para a engine que ela não use locks mas ela pode escolher escalar o lock e muitas vezes ela o faz quando lida com muitos dados de uma vez. Quanto ao seu update, tente faze-lo durante uma janela de manutenção, você tem ideia de quantos registros serão atualizados?

Comment: @jean, cerca de 2,5 milhões

Comment: Todos os registros rerão atualizados?! Bem, aconselho a usar realmente uma janela de manutenção, deixar o banco em single mode, aproveitar p/ fazer um backup, quem sabe um reindex e mandar ver.

Comment: Criei um index para a coluna a alterar, rodei em uma janela de manutenção e foi relativamente rápido: 1min30

Comment: @AndréFigueiredo, mas a coluna apenas é utilizada como filtragem? Ou existe leitura em alguma query de todas as colunas dessa tabela?

Answer (score 2):

Viva,

Existem algumas soluções para esse problema:

1 - A martelada (Não testado)

Você pode alterar temporariamente o nome da tabela, criar uma view com o nome que a tabela tinha anteriormente com o WITH(NOLOCK) e fazer o update à tabela. Após o UPDATE ser executado, você elimina a VIEW e faz o rename à tabela para o nome original.

2 - UPDATES parcelados

Em vez de fazer UPDATE à tabela toda de uma vez, você pode/deve fazer updates mais pequenos.

```
UPDATE TOP(1000) tabela SET enviado = 1 WHERE enviado is null

WHILE @@rowcount > 0
BEGIN
   UPDATE TOP(1000) tabela SET enviado = 1 WHERE enviado is null;
END
```

O que isto vai fazer, é executar o UPDATE até que nenhum registo tenha sido alterado.

3 - Criar uma nova tabela e copiar os dados

Você pode também criar uma nova tabela (*tabela_v2*) com a nova estrutura que pretende adicionar (Uma coluna com default value por exemplo) e copiar o antigo conteúdo da
*tabela* para a *tabela_v2* até ao último Id conhecido. O truque aqui está em adicionar triggers na tabela *tabela* para sincronizar a informação enquanto os dados estão a ser copiados. No final, o processo é semelhante ao primeiro ponto, o rename da *tabela* para *tabela_old* e rename da *tabela_v2* para *tabela*. e terá os seus dados atualizados e a nova estrutura sem qualquer downtime.

4 - SQL Parallel Boost (http://sqlparallelboost.codeplex.com)
Pode dar sempre uma vista de olhos neste site.

Espero que tenha sido útil.

Comment: O update parcelado é uma boa. Quanto à martelada, podem ocorrer inúmeros problemas: triggers na tabela, a própria ooperação de rename vai dar um tablock, outras transações de insert/update podem estar ocorrendo, etc

Comment: Sim, a martelada é perigosa e não deve ser usava. Se calhar na ordem da resposta, deveria ser a última.

Comment: Dependendo do BD desativar o audit e executar em modo exclusivo, depois reativa o audit, mas já fiz algo parecido (até no volume) em Oracle e só precisei fazer numa hora de BD ocioso, sem maiores preocupações só ter espaço na área de rollback, se houver triggers na tabela dar um disable temporário também.